# Synchronize SQL Server over 'my own' comm. protocol

Tags: .net, sql-server, synchronization

I am looking for a way to with little effort sync a master database (SQL Server) to several clients.

A requirement in the project is to use a 'home made' communication protocol that already is in place for other software's. Basically the protocol can send/receive byte arrays to/from clients.

I have been reading about Sync Services for ADO.NET, seems to need quite a bit of programming and I have not found any proof that I can tunnel through the communication solution I have to use.

Any suggestions or ideas on what design and technologies to use?

Comment: Homemade communication protocol? The only solution I can think of is "run away." But that isn't very helpful :-)

Comment: +1. Your best possible outcome is to re-create technology that's already been implemented elsewhere, and your chances of achieving success are rather low. Challenge your 'home-made' communication protocol requirement -- the options there are much easier than this approach.